# How to add objects from GeoJSON to OpenLayers map one at a time?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, geojson

Let's say I have three lines each stored as a LineString to put in a GeoJSON. How can I access an individual LineString and add it to be displayed on an OpenLayers map? I know I can use something like:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
  })
});
```

Then add this layer to the map, but this adds all the objects in the GeoJSON to the map.

I'd like a function that will add a LineString to the map with something like `function addLine(lineID)` if you can give each line an id.

Using openlayers 4